# call api serially in angular with rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-services

suppose i have 3 service which is called in app.component and each services subscribe() in its own service, so how can i get response one by one.

app.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
  this._salesstageService.refreshSalesstage();
  this._opportunityMailsService.RefreshTop50();
  this._opportunityService.getOpportunities();
}
```

as example, i have three service.ts file but here you can see one service function to call api.

app.service.ts

```
   getOpportunities() {
       return this.http.get(this._opportunitiesUrl)
        .do(res => this._errorService.checkResponse(res))
        .map(res => <Opportunity[]>JSON.parse(res.text(), 
              this.opportunityReviver))
        .catch(err => this._errorService.handleError<Opportunity[]>(err))
        .subscribe(
          opportunities => {
            if(opportunities instanceof Array){
                this._opportunities = opportunities;
               this.opportunities$.next(this._opportunities);
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: Add the signatures of those services, ideally their implementations as well

Answer (score 0):

Since your services seem to publish observables, subscribe to them in a nested fashion.

```
this._salesstageService.salesstage$.subscribe(() => {
  this._opportunityMailsService.RefreshTop50();
  this._opportunityMailsService.mail$.subscribe(() => this._opportunityService.getOpportunities());
});

this._salesstageService.refreshSalesstage();
```

Comment: I think, It will not work, because subscribe will call whenever api get updated, but these 3 api services will call once at time in the app.component and it should call serially.

Comment: chaining them will call them serially. you subscribe inside the other subscribe methods.